# Putting an Image behind RGBA

Tags: html, image, rgba

How would I put an image behind, RGBA?

**Original Code:**

```
<div style="width: 266px; height: 266px; border: 3px solid red;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 49.25%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50.75%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 49.25%, rgba(255,230,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50.75%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);">
</div>
```

**I changed it to this:** It's not working though.

```
<div style="width: 266px; height: 266px; border: 3px solid red;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 0%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 49.25%,
           rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 50.75%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 0%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 49.25%,
           rgba(255,230,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 50.75%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 100%), url(\'http://via.placeholder.com/260x260\');">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove unwanted `\` from image url. Check below snippet for reference.

```html
<div style="width: 266px; height: 266px; border: 3px solid red;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 0%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 49.25%,
           rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 50.75%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 0%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 49.25%,
           rgba(255,230,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 50.75%,
           rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.0) 100%), url('http://via.placeholder.com/260x260');">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a content wrapper and put the image as the background of the wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/260x260');
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
}

.rgba {
  background: rgba(100, 255, 0, .5);
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rgba">
  </div>
</div>
```